# Prevent Google Chrome from launching external handler for custom url

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, chromium

I installed an app that was associated with a custom url (not sure how it occurred) in Google Chrome for a specific site. It sucked so I uninstalled the app. However, Google Chrome continues to allow the request to reach Windows resulting with a

> You'll need a new app to open this *** link

[image: You'll need a new app to open this *** link]

This pass through does not occur on my other chromium browsers (ie Edge, etc).

I have disabled google chrome protocol handlers yet this link keeps popping up.

**How do I block this pass through?**

Answer (score 0):

You can block specific websites from handling protocols via the Chrome Protocol handlers settings page: `chrome://settings/handlers`

(Settings -> Privacy and security -> Site Settings -> Permissions -> Additional Permissions -> Protocol Handlers)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).